# Downloading the image produced by LDAvis library

Tags: python, ipython, gensim, lda

I am using the topic visualization library LDAvis:

```
## visualization of the topics
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(ldamodel, corpus, dictionary)
```

which produces an image of the Principal Components of the topics unveiled by the LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) model. I will like to download the image but I am stuck. Any help much appreciated it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save the HTML file like this in Python:

```
vis_data = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda, corpus, dictionary)
pyLDAvis.save_html(vis_data, 'output_filename.html')
```

Or you can use SVG Crowbar to download the SVG node from the page it's already loaded in.